# Accessing entity from controller: To repository pattern or not to

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I know below code is wrong as I'm not supposed to access entity straight from Controller. So I'm thinking of using repository pattern - but after doing some googling around, there are a lot of people against Repository pattern.

Being new to design patterns, how would I rewrite below to make it tick all the checkboxes in SOLID principles and maybe use a design pattern? Also, do I use TDD for database logic such as below?

Silly first question i know.

Controller:

```
    public void Put(User userData)
    {
        using (var dataContext = new UserEntities())
        {
            dataContext.User.Add(userData);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at these: [http://prodinner.codeplex.com/] and [http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/08/12/solid-design-principles-in-net-the-single-responsibility-principle/]. I have them bookmarked. I've implemented the UOW + Generic Repository pattern in some of my projects. They are useful for testing however, sometimes, it is best not to overcomplicated your code...

Comment: @Praval'Shaun'Tirubeni - Neither of your links work

Comment: Accidentally added a bracket to the URL. Try http://prodinner.codeplex.com/ and http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/08/12/solid-design-principles-in-net-the-single-responsibility-principle/